# several select dropdown boxes to add values

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

How can I find the values of two different select dropdowns and add the two values together upon selection(not submition) if they have the same "name" and then place the sum value into an array using jquery?

**EDIT**

For a little clarification, I am dynamically creating the list which needs to look like this

BOX A, BOX A, TITLE

BOX B, BOX B, TITLE

BOX C, BOX C, TITLE
etc...

Every list will be different and rarely the same. Next time the boxes could be D E or F. When selected(currently .onchange) All corresponding boxes need to be added together then pushed into a seperate array if the value is not empty...

> var s=[sumOfAs, sumOfBs, sumOfCs];

I hope this helps...
Also the back end is PHP
THANKS!

EDIT

Here is the jquery code that pushes the first set of values into an array...

```
$("#selectionBox select").change(function(){
    s = [];
    $("#selectionBox select option:selected").each(function(){
        $("#selected_songs").text('');

        var v = $(this).val();
        if(v != ''){
            s.push(v);
        }
        if(s != ""){ 
            $('#selectionButton').show(); 
            var mw = $("#list_month_New").val();
            var dw = $("#list_day_New").val();
            var yw = $("#list_year_New").val();
            var t = $("#listTitle").val();
            if(mw == "" || dw == "" || yw == ""){
                $("#songListWarning").show();
            }else{
                $("#songListWarning").hide();
            }
        }else{
            $("#list_month_New").val();
            $("#list_day_New").val();
            $("#list_year_New").val();
            $("#listTitle").val();
            $('#selectionButton').hide();
        }
    });
    s.sort();
    jQuery.each(s, function(){
            O = "";
            O = this+"<br />";
            str = /&(.+)/.exec(O)[1];
            num = O.replace(/\-.*/, '');
            fullString = '<span style="color:black">'+num+'</span> - '+str;
            $("#selected_songs").append(fullString);
    });
```

I just need to figure out how to add another value to the initial value?

Comment: Two inputs cannot have the same name within a form unless the name is an array like `names[]`.

Comment: My goal is to allow someone to select from two boxes that need to be added together and then displayed on the screen upon selection. The problem is that I have about 200 items to choose from and each item has a companion. When they are added together only the boxes that are not empty will display on screen and then once I have cross refrenced my selection I can submit. Any ideas?

Comment: @PhpMyCoder That is untrue.  I believe it is true for php but not other languages.

Comment: @JamesMontagne I'm not 100% sure. In PHP you could get at the original querystring and find the duplicates for yourself. Although I suspect there are other language that mimmic PHP's argument parsing.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder Incorrect.  The browser will do this:  `...x=one&x=two&x=3...`.  It is up to the backend to then parse that.  PHP is the only language I know of which makes you add `[]`.

Comment: @JamesMontagne That's why I said "you could get at the original querystring and find the duplicates for yourself." PHP uses the last value because `$_GET` and `$_POST` are superglobal arrays. But PHP isn't that only language (or framework) that stores GET and POST variables in arrays (which would only allow for each key to have one unique value).

Comment: You edited your comment...  Many languages concatenate the values into one string with some separator.  But naming with `[]` I believe is a php creation.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder Ijust edited my post for further clarification. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var runningTotals = {};
$('select').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var name = $this.attr("name");
    var val = runningTotals[name];
    if (!val) {
        val = 0;
    }
    val += +($this.val());
    runningTotals[name] = val;
});
```

Please refer to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zmhN/1/)

---

**EDIT**
Edited to update for the change edit you made

Comment: with this, you can put the runningTotal into an array.  Please note, like @PhpMyCoder pointed out, you should make sure your name is in the correct format ;)

Comment: The `[]` thing is for php.  He hasn't stated what backend he is using.

Comment: ah, ic...regardless this solution should work for the desired case

Comment: This is close, the problem is that I am dynamically creating the list of select boxes and there are two sets of multiple sets of names that will rarely be the same. The only names that will be the same will be box a and box b, but box c and box d will be different from the previous set. I don't know if I am making any sense here...

Comment: @JuanGonzales -- the new solution should work; it doesn't put the values into an array, but in the fiddle, there is a `for(var i in runningTotals)` loop, and you can just populate an array there.

Comment: This is great but how can i incorporate this with on change it will add the two values together and then display them on screen on change.

Comment: Also the values I am using are text values such as "song1" + "'Key' D" should equal song 1 D.

Comment: @JuanGonzales -- do you mean it should equal "song1 'Key' D"

Comment: @Skyrim yes, the idea is the first field is the song order with a value of "the order number" as well as the "title" and the second field is the key which can be A-G, but I am generating the song from a database and everyone in the site has a different list of songs. When they click the order, in my example code, it pops up in #selected_songs div as well as sorts the array into numerical order, but I would like to add a select box where they can also pick a key and it will show up right next to the song associated with it. Sorry, I should have included this information in the original post.